# Notify when some grouped services fail in Nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios, service

I have three DNS services, each on different hosts configured in Nagios. Each service notifies me whenever it is failing (DNS on host A down).

Is it possible to configure Nagios so that I'm only getting a (customized) notification when all three DNS services are down via pager (DNS is not working) and a mail in case only a single service goes down (DNS on host A down).

The only way I see how I could achieve something like this is with service dependencies, which are cumbersome to use. They also do not have their own notifications.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [check_cluster](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/clusters.html) Nagios plugin? With it you can set DNS service state to warning if only one node is down and error if everything goes down, for example.

Comment: That's much more like it - +1 from me!

Comment: I think that's gonna do exactly what I want.. Thank you! :)

Comment: This is exactly what check_multi is for. check_cluster can do it, but it's very clumsy.

Just search Serverfault for "check_multi". It's been answered.